# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'language' to song without a default; we can't do that

Tags: django, django-models

#Get this error

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'language' to song without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 2000)
    singer = models.CharField(max_length= 2000)
    language = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'docs')
    song = models.FileField(upload_to= 'docs')
    movie = models.CharField(max_length = 150, default = "None")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: That's not an error. It simply asks what to fill in for the `language` field you added for the *existing* `Song` records.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
```